# ubuntu 13.04 - can't see external ntfs drive

Tags: 13.04, ntfs, external-hdd

I have upgraded from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 (x64) and from kde v4.10 to v4.11. Same kernel 3.8.
Since the upgrade I have an issue with my Verbatim store'n go 500Gb usb external drive recognition, it takes a lot of time before recognize my external drive. I'll give you some more informations:

- it just happens with my external drive and it does not with my usb pen drives
- it happens on ubuntu but it works well on windows 7 (windows 7 immediately recognizes the external drive as it does with other devices) so it's not related to my external drive
- it's not related to my usb port because it's the same I use to connect the same external drive on windows 7
- it doesn't happen with other external drives (so it's very strange now)
- The same external drive was immediately recognized with ubuntu 12.10
- it's not related to the desktop environment because I have the same issue with unity
- sometimes the drive is seen with 'sudo fdisk -l' but it's not recognized from the file manager (same thing with unity and kde)

How can I solve it?

**edit**: 
here is /etc/fstab:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QPawt31b

and this it /proc/mounts: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ub4F1XuW

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of */proc/mounts*  when the drive is plugged in? What is in */etc/fstab*?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems (but not sure) that Ubuntu changes the way the devices are mounted now using subfolders for each user in /media
So if you launch Nautilus as root and see your files so just it's a matter of rights.
try this from a shell:

```
sudo -i nautilus --no-desktop
```